# Usage of "mueco" vs. "mellado" for "toothless"

Tags: etimología, sinónimos, colombia

The [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=mueco) does not have an entry for *mueco* or *mueca*, a term commonly used in Colombia to describe a [toothless person](http://books.google.com/books?id=e-fPeBQ7NxgC&pg=PA167&dq=mueco&hl=en&ei=soXmTt7kOuunsAKK5NiIBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=mueco&f=false). However, the expression *hacer muecas* is understood in the traditional sense as [a generally burlesque facial contorsión](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=mueca). [Mellado](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=mellado) seems to be used outside of Colombia to describe a toothless person. Based on my experience, the term *mellado* is not common in Colombia.

- Is *mueco* used elsewhere to describe a toothless person?
- How widespread is the use of *mellado*?
- Can the use of *mueco* be traced back to Spain or did it come about in Colombia?

---

La [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=mueco) no tiene un artículo para *mueco* o *mueca*, una palabra común en Colombia para describir a una persona [persona desdentada](http://books.google.com/books?id=e-fPeBQ7NxgC&pg=PA167&dq=mueco&hl=en&ei=soXmTt7kOuunsAKK5NiIBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=mueco&f=false). Sin embargo, la expresión *hacer muecas* se entiende en el sentido tradicional como [una contorsión facial generalmente burlesca](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=mueca). [Mellado](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=mellado) parece ser usado fuera de Colombia para describir a alguien carente de dientes. Basado en mi experiencia, la palabra *mellado* no es común en Colombia.

- ¿Se usa *mueco* en algún otro lugar para describir una persona desdentada?
- ¿Qué tan predominante es el uso de *mellado* en este contexto?
- ¿Es posible trazar el uso de *mueco* a España o se originó en Colombia?

Comment: mueca tiene entrada en la RAE como expresión burlesca, ¿a lo mejor la expresión colombiana derivó de que la cara de alguien sin dientes parece "hacer muecas"? En España no lo oí nunca.

Comment: Is the first time I heard the word "mueco", and it is also the first time I see "mellado" used in this way. Where I come from we use "desdentado".

Comment: En Puerto Rico se usa la palabra *mueco* también y con la misma connotación que en Colombia. *Mellado* tambien es de uso muy común en Puerto Rico.

Comment: También en Guatemala se usa la palabra con el mismo significado de no tener los dientes del frente.

Answer (score 4):

`Mellado/a` is common used in Spanish for children who are losing their milk teeth.

For an adult you can use `sin dientes` or `desdentado`.

Comment: That is: 'desdentado' is literally what toothless means. +1

Answer (score 1):

I had never heard about `mueco` before, so it really can be a very localized word.

About `mellado`, it usually is used to refer someone who lacks one o more teeth, but is not exactly toothless, which then is told `desdentado`.
It derives from `mella`, which the RAE defines as:

> Vacío o hueco que queda en una cosa por faltar lo que lo ocupaba o
>   henchía, como en la encía cuando falta un diente.

it is, an empty space left where there should be something (as a tooth at the gum).